# CAPL Scripting - CAN C communication (Stop transmitting one message from DBC)

Tags: can-bus, capl

I am working on a CAPL script that has to allow all messages to transmit on a CAN C channel and stop transmitting one particular message from the database file. 
Can anyone help with the method/function/code I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vague, but I'm assuming you are going from one CAN channel to another.  For instance, CAN C to CAN D (or CAN 3 to CAN 4), than you could do:

```
on message CAN3.0x7FF  // This would be that one ID that stops at some point
{
  message CAN4.0x7FF msg;
  msg = this;

  // Assuming you are receiving on CAN 3, and looking to transmit on CAN 4
  if(this.dir == rx)
  {
      // Declare a global variable that sets to 1 when you want it to stop
    if(MSG_STOP == 0)
       output(msg);
  }
}

on message CAN3.*
{

  message CAN4.* msg;
  msg = this;
  if (this.dir == rx)
  {
    output (msg);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the only way to accomplish this is to disable any automatic transmission of messages (e.g. via the IG or Network IL) and transmit all messages manually from your CAPL script in timer callbacks. Transmission can be done using the `output` function and based on whichever criteria you define, you can choose not to call `output` for any messages which should be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Interaction Layer (IL) in your simulation, and the DBC file cyclic times are correctly configured there are some CAPL functions that can be used for fault injection which will allow you to selectively start/stop transmitting certain messages:

```
on sysvar Sys_m0x461_Send {
/**********************************************************
 * FAULT INJECTION Enable/Disable Msg Sending
 **********************************************************/
  if (@this) {
    ILFaultInjectionEnableMsg(Message0x461fromDBC);
  }
  else {
    ILFaultInjectionDisableMsg(Message0x461fromDBC);
  }
}
```

In the example if the system variable (could be linked to a panel control, e.g. checkbox) equals '1' the message will transmit as defined in the DBC, otherwise the message sending is stopped.